# how to get directions from google map?

Tags: objective-c

I want to develop an application which gives directions in text format from source to destination using google map.Please give me some example which gives direction from source to destination in text format(ie in english language)eg:turn right from xxx.
thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've needed this functionality I just hit their URL and supply my own arguments.

In the following, "**saddr**" is the start address and "**daddr**" is the destination address. This will open it up in "Print Mode" which I believe is the closest you can get to plain text.

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=Six+Flags+Great+Adventure,+Jackson+,+NJ&daddr=1200+Epcot+Resorts+Boulevard,+Orlando,+FL+32830-8429+%28Walt+Disney+World+Swan+and+Dolphin+Resort%29&hl=en&mra=ls&ie=UTFz=6&layer=c&pw=2

Comment: hey thanx for your reply but can you please give the code of how to send the request and parse the response to get the output?

Comment: The only times I've sent requests and parsed responses is in C# not Objective-C. Why not open a browser control and just navigate to the url? Let that interface serve as your directions view.